# How to access my prometheus dashboard which are running in aws multiContainer docker?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prometheus

I have running prometheus and grafana images on aws docker which are  running in respective **0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp**  & **0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp** ports in docker but i don't know how to access this prometheus and grafana dashboard using endpoints. I tried to access using (MachineIP:9090) but it's not accessible. Can anyone have idea about that?

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/php-app"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy-conf",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/proxy/conf.d"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "image": "php:fpm",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/sample-app"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy",
      "image": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "php-app"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "nginx-proxy-conf",
          "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i assume you have successfully deployed. can you post your `Dockerrun.aws.json`

Comment: I have added the Dockerrun.aws.json file check it @ArunK

Comment: good. we need to find out whether you have a public ip address for your instance. can you goto `elasticbeanstalk` and see whether you have a load balancer /

Comment: No. as of now i don't have any load balancer for my ebs

Comment: ok. if you find the security group and allow port 80 and 9090, you can access it via the ip address

Comment: From where i can access this security group?

Comment: Ok to your ec2 console

Comment: select the instance, in the details of the instance, you will see security group

Comment: check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: were you able to do it

Comment: I am trying....

Comment: First rule: protocol http , source `anywhere`

Comment: Second rule protocol tcp, port `9090` , source `anywhere`

Comment: thanks man, its's working..:)

Comment: glad to be of help, approve the answer and upvote if its helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do a port mapping between the elastic beans talk load balancer and your docker instance.

Also make sure to allow port `80` and `9090` in the security group

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: Can you explain how briefly?

Comment: you mean running the prometheus?

Comment: yes , can you explain how did you deploy to elasticbeanstalk

Comment: the ip address that you tried use, does it start with ``10.x.x.x` or `172.x.x.x`  or `192.x.x.x`  if yes , you cant use that ip address to access

Comment: No, i am trying with AWS public IP address start with 13.x.x.x

Comment: thats good, you need to modify your security group to allow you in. can you find the security group of the instance